# Zapier send log files from Azure to Loggly

Tags: javascript, xml, zapier

I need to get the latest log file from a log index on Azure like this:
https://logs2000.blob.core.windows.net/logs?restype=container&comp=list

And send them over to a Loggly endpoint like this:
https://logs-01.loggly.com/inputs/TOKEN/tag/http/

Is this possible with zapier?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the format of your logging, but this Zapier Python code works for me.
Wouldn't know how to get your logging into Zapier. Maybe you would be better off sending the logging directly to Zapier.

Zapier puts input data in the dict input_data.

```js
LOGGLY_URL = "https://logs-01.loggly.com/inputs/TOKEN/tag/watchmouse/";
logging = {'source': 'Zapier'}
logging.update(input_data)
r = requests.post(LOGGLY_URL, data = logging)
r.raise_for_status() 
return r.json()
```